# Add headers to a SQL (Sybase) output

Tags: sql, unix, header, sybase

I have created a a script that execute sql (Sybase)

```
#!/bin/bash
command=$(
isql -U databasename_dba  -P password   -b <<EOF!
select label1, label2 from TABLE
go
EOF!
)

echo "$command" >> output_file.csv):
```

All good so far, the file is produced:

[image: Output]

But as you can see, the output is represented in 1 column.

Is possible to add "Headers" and divide the column is 2 columns, my desired output would be:

[image: Desidered Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove -b.

```
#!/bin/bash
command=$(
isql -U databasename_dba  -P password <<EOF!
select label1, label2 from TABLE
go
EOF!
)

echo "$command" >> output_file.csv):
```

Comment: Have a nice day @VBoka

Comment: @LorenzoCastagno You too!